# How to enlarge edittext when focussed. (like google chrome url field)

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, android-edittext

How can I enlarge edittext when being focussed and back to default when unfoccused. (like google chrome url field)

The edittext is @+id/edittext

Here is my code:
--custom_actionbar--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:hint="@string/url"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSend"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:background="#ffe0e0e0"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get reference to your edit text in your activity and apply focus listener :

Define NORMAL and LARGE as two text sizes

```
edit_Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
           this.setTextSize(LARGE);
    }else {
           this.setTextSize(NORMAL);
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: Can i do this with an animation like google chrome does

Comment: And i tried this and it didn't help it only makes it bigger and doesn't do it like google chrome.